# How to fetch all stock locations under a warehouse in Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to fetch all stock locations which are under a specific warehouse in Odoo 15.
I tried the below code.

```
locations_dd.append(self.env['stock.location'].search([('warehouse_id','=',i)]).ids)
```

But I am getting the below error:

> ERROR odoo15ee odoo.osv.expression: Non-stored field stock.location.warehouse_id cannot be searched.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[warehouse_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/stock/models/stock_location.py#L90) is a non-stored computed field, you can't use it in the search domain.

You can use the stock location `location_id` field (which is the parent location) and the warehouse view location field (`view_location_id`) to get all warehouse locations.

***Example:***

```
location_ids = self.env['stock.location'].search([('location_id', 'child_of', warehouse_id.view_location_id.id)])
```